# MD5 Hashes failing for large Strings

Tags: java, hash, md5

I'm making a MD5 hash of a response, and then signing it with a shared secret.

For most calls this works, but strangely fails (Generates a MD5 hash different from the client) on the only two calls that bring a lot of content in the body.

Can this be because of the size of the body? or maybe because those calls return the content `chunked`?

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

The hashing code (note that `algorithm == MD5` and `ENCODING == 'UTF-8'`):

```
private static byte[] hash(String toHash, String algorithm){
      try{
      MessageDigest dg = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
      dg.update(toHash.getBytes(ENCODING));
      return dg.digest();
    }catch(Exception e){
      throw new ApiInternalException("Error while hashing string: " + toHash,e);
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the code you use to generate the MD5, there are more ways than one.

Comment: I recall your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181215/md5-signing-a-httpservletresponse How about if you actually try my answer? :)

Comment: @BalusC thanks but that's a totally different question. One is about how to read contents from a OutputStream and this is about MD5 signatures failing. Thanks anyway

Comment: You should indeed be more specific about how it fails. What happens? Any exception? Which one? Trace please.

Comment: By fail I mean that the hash calculated by the client does not match the one generated by the server. And _no_ the server does not modify the body after generating the hash.

Comment: Well, it really sounds like not **everything** has been written through *your* writer, as I initially already suspected (in my deleted answer). But OK, hope you get it nailed down.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be great if you included your code.  Without that, I can only guess what the problem is.  Anyway, here's the correct way to create an MD5 hash in Java.  If your code differs from this, then you have a problem.

```
String plainString = "Hash me please";
String md5Hash = "NOTHASHED";
try {
     MessageDigest md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
     md5String = new String(md5Digest.digest(plainString.getBytes()));
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
     // MD5 is included in all versions of Java, this can never happen
}
```

Of course, this will return something that looks like: `�ǚ���;�f���&fu`
If you want it to be human readable, it's usually suggested that you Bas64 encode it, in which case just use the line:

```
new String(Base64Encoder.encode((md5Digest.digest(DESKTOP_STRING.getBytes()))));
```

Which will give you something that looks like: `ssea19zwO6Jm3AiF4SZmdQ==`

Keeping in mind that you will need to *unencode* it later before using it as an md5 hash.

Comment: Erm, the nomal practice is that you format the bytearray as a hexstring. Also see my answer on the OP's previous question on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181215/md5-signing-a-httpservletresponse

Comment: I'm doing something similar but the encoding is in hexa instead of `Base64`, check the edit! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Either explanation is plausible.  Other possible explanation include:

- something (maybe a proxy server) is altering content in transit,
- there is a mismatch in the way that character encoding / decoding is being dealt with
- it is actually the MD5 hashes that are being damaged.

You need to gather more information to figure out which it is.  I suggest that you modify your client and server sides to capture the data being sent / received into files, move them to the same machine and do a byte-wise comparison.  Other things you could try include turning off chunking and dumping / comparing the MD5 checksums at both ends.

**EDIT** : It would also help us help you if you posted the code that does the MD5 checksum calculation at both ends, and the code that encodes / decodes the checksums for transmission (e.g. using hexadecimal, base64 or whatever).

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the html response being `chunked`?

Comment: @Pablo - as I said, either of your two proposed explanations is plausible.  But you need to figure out which of the plausible explanations is the actual one.