# ServletRequestWrapper or ServletResponseWrapper in production?

Tags: java, servlets

Hi have you seen anything really useful extending `HttpServletResponseWrapper`/`HttpServletRequestWrapper` or  `ServletRequestWrapper`/ `ServletResponseWrapper` in production environment?

Comment: This should probably be community wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Trim whitespace](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/whitespacefilter.html) from generated HTML, can save over 50% of bandwidth. I've had a project which displays large tabular data (with nicely indented HTML source), response size went from ~200KB to ~70KB by just trimming all whitespace away.
- Process multipart/form-data requests transparently by putting multipart form data back in request parameter map so that you can use `request.getParameter()` and consorts the usual way again ([Servlet <=2.5 example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html), [Servlet >=3.0 example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html#MoreAbstraction)).
- Capture the outputstream, either to have a [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963158/capture-generated-dynamic-content-at-server-side/1963571#1963571) or to [MD5-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181215/md5-signing-a-httpservletresponse/2181332#2181332) it.
- [Disabling URL rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276920/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-not-encode-the-session-id-into-the-url-when-httpservle/2276982#2276982).

Etcetera.. Etcetera.. All just to override and change the default behaviour of certain `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse` methods.

Answer (score 3):

I've used it to "capture" the output of a JSP, so that it can be transformed by the forwarding controller. This was done by overriding the `getWriter()` / `getOutputStream()` methods.

SiteMesh does a similar thing, capturing the "target" in order to decorate the response.

Answer (score 2):

We use it to

- overwrite `getRemoteAddr()` to return values from `X-Forwarded-For` or `X-Real-IP` (set by our nginx proxy)
- filter certain headers, e.g. to avoid content negotiation in 3rd party servlets
- gzip response

Comment: GZIP is just configreable in any decent servlet container. In Tomcat for example, just set `<Connector compression="on">`: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: @balusc we've been using embedded Jetty. see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/GZIP+Compression and http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/xref/org/mortbay/servlet/GzipFilter.html

Answer (score 2):

- Many frameworks (richfaces, myfaces on my current classpath at least) use a request wrapper to handle multipart requests
- Spring has `ContextExposingHttpServletRequest` so that spring beans are accessible as request attributes.
- myfaces orchestra uses the response wrapper to rewrite the URL in order to ensure multiple-window conversation context

Answer (score 2):

I've used it just recently to capture outgoing response headers for debugging purposes (`getHeaderNames()` and `getHeader()` were only added on the response side in the Servlet 3.0 spec.

We've also used it for gathering metrics on our servlets, by overriding `getOutputStream()` to return an `OutputStream` implementation which increases a counter on every byte that passes through it so we can tell what our high-network-traffic servlets are.